# unexpected end of stream in Retrofit-2.0

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to post some data to my API usind Retrofit2 but I'm getting error of "time out" for the first try and sometimes "Unexpected end of stream" What could be the reasons ??
I'm using the below code :

```
Interface : 
interface APIService  {
@Headers("Authorization: ***************")
@POST("corona-watch-api/v1/reports/suspected-cases")
fun uploadImageToApi(@Body suspect_cas :suspected  ): Call<suspected?>?}
```

In main Activity i'm using this function to post data to my API:

```
  fun PostDataToApi(){

    var user : ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()
    user.add(98)
    var attach = Attachment("3","ff","hh","hh","rrr")
    var cas_suspect =  suspected (attach,"hhh",false,"jjj",user)

    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

    okHttpClient.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor).build()
    okHttpClient.retryOnConnectionFailure(true)

    okHttpClient.addInterceptor { chain ->
        val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .header("Accept", "application/json")
            .addHeader("Connection", "close")
            .build()
        chain.proceed(request)
    }

    val BaseUrl = "http://corona-watch-api.herokuapp.com/"
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
        .client(okHttpClient.build())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val service = retrofit.create(APIService::class.java)
    val call = service.uploadImageToApi(cas_suspect)


    call!!.enqueue(object : Callback<suspected?> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<suspected?>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("log", "Unable to submit post to API." + t.message)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<suspected?>, response: Response<suspected?>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                println(response.body()!!.toString())
                Log.i( "log","post submitted to API." + response.body()!!.toString())
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your API works correctly on the backend? These errors look like backend issue.

Comment: I tried to pass the data manually from Postman API and it is working fine